# Does a bootstrap distribution of the mean statistic give us uncertainity of our overall sampling procedure?

Tags: sampling, bootstrap

Say that we bootstrapped the mean statistic, and we get a wide bootstrap distribution. Does this give us intuition on the issues with sampling?

That is, if we have a wide bootstrap distribution, does this mean that our sampling procedure was flawed?

Comment: You can't infer inadequacies of sampling procedure from a bootstrap distribution. A "wide" distribution could just reflect a small sample from a highly variable distribution with no "sampling issues" at all.

Comment: Interesting. My logic was that: the width of the distribution describes some uncertainty of this statistic. If the underlying distribution has poor kurtosis then it is due to the nature of the data itself.

Comment: Unrelated: how could I estimate the inadequacies of sampling procedure then?

Comment: Sometimes the data tell you; usually only moving upstream to analyse what  was done in data production will give insight.

Comment: Width and kurtosis are completely separate properties. You appear to be mixing quite different questions there.